# JOIN/UPDATE TABLES WITH CONDITIONAL STATEMENT?

Tags: mysql, join

i have a registry table `( id , counter , group_name , type )`

and group tables which includes these tables

```
software_group  
website_group
news_group 
 etc ..
```

every group is in the registry table  as well as it's own group table

now if i want to update a row in the registry i want appropriate group table to updated too

`type` column indicates the group table so i have it something like :

```
UPDATE registry JOIN 

CASE WHEN registry.type = 1 THEN software_group 
CASE WHEN registry.type = 2 THEN website_group
CASE WHEN registry.type = 3 THEN news_group 

AS other_table 

ON registry.id = other_table.reg_id
  SET registry.name = $newname
  ,
  other_table.name = $newname

WHERE registry.id = $id
```

is it possible to do something like this ?  i can just select the registry row and do the job with php but i thought join/update would be faster than select/update

Comment: I don't think you can update values inside `other_table`

Answer (score 0):

I think the dynamic join to tables on run time will be best if you handle the conditions in application layer, rather than the DB layer